# Is it possible to retrieve actual data of the ContentVersion record by using the Salesforce CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, contentversion

I would like to retrieve the Base64 data of the `ContentVersion` file stored in my Org. The requirement is to do so by using the Salesforce CLI, though.

I identified two potential commands that could help me accomplish this task but neither succeeded. Instead of the data, I receive a URL for the `ContentVersion` that I could use in the potential SOAP/REST API call.

Is there any special parameter that needs to be added in order to receive the actual contents of the file or it's just impossible to do just by using the CLI and I must utilize the API?

Extra question: In case the standalone CLI won't help me here, is there any option to utilize it to overcome the burden of setting the whole authorization process in the custom app? Like, to generate a bearer token? I browsed through the available resources but I couldn't find anything useful.

For `sfdx force:data:soql:query`:

```
PS C:\sfdx> sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = \'0680Q000002EYCqQAO\'" -u MyAlias -r json

{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "done": true,
    "totalSize": 1,
    "records": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "ContentVersion",
          "url": "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0680Q000002EYCqQAO"
        },
        "VersionData": "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0680Q000002EYCqQAO/VersionData"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For `sfdx force:data:record:get`:

```
PS C:\sfdx> sfdx force:data:record:get -s ContentVersion -i 0680Q000002EYCqQAO -u MyAlias

attributes:
  type: ContentVersion
  url: /services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0680Q000002EYCqQAO
Id: 0680Q000002EYCqQAO
ContentDocumentId: 0690Q0000020dZIQAY
IsLatest: true
ContentUrl: null
ContentBodyId: 05T0Q000005cF52UAE
VersionNumber: 1
Title: 10
Description: null
ReasonForChange: null
SharingOption: A
SharingPrivacy: N
PathOnClient: 10.log
RatingCount: 0
IsDeleted: false
ContentModifiedDate: 2022-05-02T01:24:28.000+0000
ContentModifiedById: 0050Q0000070o0hQAA
PositiveRatingCount: 0
NegativeRatingCount: 0
FeaturedContentBoost: null
FeaturedContentDate: null
CurrencyIsoCode: DKK
OwnerId: 0050Q0000070o0hQAA
CreatedById: 0050Q0000070o0hQAA
CreatedDate: 2022-05-02T01:24:28.000+0000
LastModifiedById: 00509000003x1ACAAY
LastModifiedDate: 2022-05-02T11:08:05.000+0000
SystemModstamp: 2022-05-02T11:08:05.000+0000
TagCsv: null
FileType: LOG
PublishStatus: P
VersionData: /services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0680Q000002EYCqQAO/VersionData
ContentSize: 10529843
FileExtension: log
FirstPublishLocationId: 0060Q00000JeteRQAR
Origin: C
NetworkId: null
ContentLocation: S
TextPreview: null
ExternalDocumentInfo1: null
ExternalDocumentInfo2: null
ExternalDataSourceId: null
Checksum: 1f61790aec916f5ec7a4bee9d52d1e11
IsMajorVersion: true
IsAssetEnabled: false
OurListingsDocumentId__c: null
Getting Record... done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a suitable workaround solution.

Salesforce CLI can be used to simplify the authorization process and then to download files via the SF REST API. By using the `sfdx force:org:display` command, one can obtain the `accessToken` which then can be utilized in the API call.

Below is the full Python example of how to retrieve the `ContentVersion` with the usage of Salesforce CLI.

```
import subprocess
import json
import requests

orgDisplayProcess = subprocess.run(['sfdx', 'force:org:display', '--json'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

orgDisplayProcessJson = json.loads(orgDisplayProcess.stdout)

instanceUrl = orgDisplayProcessJson['result']['instanceUrl']
accessToken = orgDisplayProcessJson['result']['accessToken']

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'X-PrettyPrint': '1'
}

response = requests.get(
    instanceUrl + '/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0680Q000002EZFKQA4/VersionData',
    headers = headers
)

with open('out', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

The file from Salesforce is saved in the local directory as `out`. I don't want to spend more time on the Python code optimization but for future readers - if it's, let's say, a PDF file, manually add a `.pdf` extension - you should be able to open it without problems.

Comment: [simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) is a good Python wrapper for SF tasks